# Show updates to a value in a controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to show updates to a value set on my controller, I have an action that will update it, but the template doesn't show these changes. If I leave the route and come back, the changes are shown.

Here is a jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/foriwu/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `this.value += 1`, you need to use Ember's object methods to change properties on an object. You could do:

```
this.set('value', this.get('value') + 1)
```

or use the shortcut

```
this.incrementProperty('value')
```

I'd recommend reading the [Ember docs on the object model](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/) for more info about this and related topics.